# How to position TextView above-left on another element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a fragment, which includes a Textview and a ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".uiFragments.WikiFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ampel_weiss"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textColor="#00000C"
            android:background="@color/ampelWE20"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/custom_list"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="1000dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_color_selector"
            android:background="@drawable/listview_border"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

For the moment, it looks now like the image below: 
[image]

You can see the "Text" on the left side. 
I would like to put the Text above the "Listview", but it should be not in the center of it, but on the left of the ListView like in the image below:

[image]

I am new in this topic, and would be happy about help, because as I know, the gravity is different then in an linearlayout.

Thanks in advice!

EDIT: 
When I use the solution in the comment below, I get this image below now. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ampel_weiss"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:text="TE"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#00000C"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/custom_list"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ampel_weiss"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: like in the second picture above. 
ListView is in center_horizontal 
and the Textview shall be above the ListView. 

But it shall not be just above the listview for example in the middle above listview. It shall be on the left of it. Means, when ListView starts in the horizontal_center, above of it, the TextView shall be

Comment: Here is the link: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBw2c.jpg 

Because the code make the textview above the listview, what I want, but listview shall be in center and textview above-left, where listview starts

Comment: As long as TextView and ListView have the same width (in the layout above), textView should remain on the top-left of the ListView.

Comment: To change the position of text inside the TextView use paddingLeft. Also, remove marginStart.

Comment: Thank you, you solved this problem. It is now, like I wanted. 

Thanks a lot! 

If you know a good method to display pdf inside app, feel free to tell me..I am looking for a good possibility

Comment: You can try: [https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I dont like it, because on my display the pdf will not displayed "full", I have to "zoom" to enlarge the file

Comment: Did you try to change the pageFitPolicy()?

Comment: Suppose that you are trying to open a PDF from a file: pdfView.fromFile(File).pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.BOTH).

Comment: Thanks, I just think I can not become friends with this library..because even if I swip vertical to change site, many sites will be changed in one time, I can not swip "soft" or "quick", it react not so good..

Comment: I post another question about pdf..I would happy if you can take a look, thanks

Comment: OK, I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Use **`LinearLayout`** instead of **`RelativeLayout`**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tablayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="50dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ampel_weiss"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:textColor="#00000C"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try now

Comment: Yes it is better, but my goal was, that the listview will be on "horizontal_center" and the TextView on the left above the listview. 

But now, everything is on the left side, but not in the middle

Comment: Now the listview is in center, but the Text is still on the left side

Comment: @NewGenerationFashion where you want to put your textview

Comment: above the listview 

                         TEXT
---------------------LISTVIEW     (center)      ---------------------------------

Comment: It shall be like in the second picture above in my post, 

both elements shall be in "center", but the listElement shall be not in the "middle of the listview, but center and left above the listview

Comment: It looks not better, I will show you in 1 min the updated image, if I use "other solution"

Comment: I updated the post with the new image with this code, textview is still left

Comment: I gave you a like on your post, because you try to help me, but problem is not solved yet

Comment: @NewGenerationFashion check now

Comment: nope, the text is on the left and the "neighbour" is the listview, so they are in the same "row"

Comment: @NewGenerationFashion can u send your project so i can check in my pc where is the problem if possible

Comment: thanks, but it would be to complicated..and complex to explain where you have to click etc to look in it..

Comment: I will read some documentations about layouts, because I assumed I had to use relative layout, because you can say where to position some element, like left, right, etc.

Comment: @NewGenerationFashion  ok no problem